# is it possible to pass a count value to view in CListView and update to each call of itemView in YII

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-extensions

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'viewData'=> array('hello'=> $loop),
                'itemView' => '_projectView',
                'template' => '{items} {pager}',
            ));
```

i would like to pass a value to my _projectView page for each loop mean for 1st row it will be 1 2nd for 2 3rd for 3 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variable called `$index` available in `CLIstView` on each item:

```
$index - the zero-based index of the item being rendered (0, 1, 2, ...)
```

This can be accessed directly in the view, eg: `echo $index`

**Note that it is zero based**, so in your first view it would have a value of 0, in your second it would have a value of 1 etc..

[Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/252/special-variables-in-cgridview-and-clistview/)